# Creating event for database through mysql connector

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-connector

What is the correct way to create an event when using MySQL connector that contains multiple statements?

For example:

```
CREATE EVENT TestEvent ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 YEAR
    DO
        <two different UPDATE statements>
```

Nothing worked so far. I tried the `BEGIN END` syntax, with or without delimiters, but no lack. I have also enabled multi queries by using the query parameter `allowMultiQueries`. From all my attempts, either it doesn't work or only the first `UPDATE` statement is added to the event body.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing so far worked. - meaning?do you get errors or does the event not get created or does the event not run? and have you enabled the scheduler? ps the create event syntax is not as you have published see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html

Comment: @P.Salmon When it runs without exceptions, only the first ``UPDATE`` statement is in the body of the event , the other is ignored for some reason (and yes, I have enabled the scheduler). The two ``UPDATE`` statements in the body have a semicolon at the end for that case. When it does not, the error is about the SQL syntax. About the create syntax, indeed it was a typo and ``CREATE EVENT`` should be written instead. Also, sometimes SQL statements may execute successfully in Java, but if the same statement is executed directly in phpMyAdmin, it does not (I don't know if that helps).